# How to query the date in mongodb without time range?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a table contains some lists like so,

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "deliveryDate": ISODate("2021-07-13T00:00:00.000Z")
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "deliveryDate": ISODate("2021-07-13T00:00:00.000Z")
}]
```

I need to get the list by `deliveryDate`.

My query,

```
model.find({deliveryDate : new Date("021-08-13T18:30:00.000Z")})
```

The problem is MongoDB looking at the correct time.
example,

```
minutes
seconds
```

but I need to check only the day.

Thanks

Comment: Why not use a time range? That is the easiest way to query any time on a day

Answer (score 0):

You can use one day range to compare between the entire day like this:

```
var firstDate = new Date(2021, 7, 13);
var secondDate = new Date(2010, 7, 14);

model.find({deliveryDate: {$gte: firstDate, $lt: secondDate}});
```

Comment: I need to check 2021-07-13 this date not with time stamp

Comment: Sorry, as I read `but I need to check only the day.` I missunderstood the question. I' ve updated answer